# Receive javascript array in java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am looking for a way to send an array from my jsp file to java servlet.

Currently I have this

```
              var members = [];
              var table = document.getElementById("my_table");
                    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                            if(table.rows[i].getAttribute("checked")==="true") {
                                members.push(table.rows[i].id.substring(2));
                            }
                    }
                    console.log(members);
          }
```

I want to send my `members` array to my servlet. The problem is that I think servlet only lets me get strings `request.getParameter("my_value");`

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

you can send the array like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/myServlet/?members=mem1&members=mem2&members=mem3
```

and in the servelt:

```
String[] arrMembers = request.getParameterValues('members');
// arrMembers = ["mem1","mem2", "mem3"]
```